# PHP mcrypt Working Sometimes Other Times Not - Totally Random

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I have a file that encrypts something on site A (let's call it: http://siteA.com/encrypt.php ) and another file on a different site that decrypts the encrypted information from site A...that second site is site B (let's call it: http://siteB.com/decrypt.php).

Using mcrypt, Site A encrypts the information, sends the encrypted information to site B (along with the IV used after encoding it with Base64 encoding), site B decrypts it and then site A gets the result of the decryption and echos it on the screen.  In addition to echoing the results of the decryption, it also echos the "iv" variable as used in mcrypt.

I'm going to provide the contents of both of those files here, but first, I'll explain the problem.

If I sit there and refresh the encryption page on Site A (which is echoing the decryption results after site B decrypts it), I get 3 different kinds of results, completely at random.

Sometimes it works perfectly, and I see echoed back on the screen the correct IV and the correct decrypted text.

Then other times, I see echoed back on the screen the completely wrong IV and the decrypted text is still encrypted.

Then other times, I get the following error message: *The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize*

This is completely random...there is no rhyme or reason to it.  Here is the source code for each file:

```
//Site A - http://SiteA.com/encrypt.php
<?php
$iv_size = "32";
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$secretkey = hash ("md5", "0yFzFSlTEb7vla5Kv3BHvKcBzX4tJBId5UKAaDDr");

$text = "something";

$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secretkey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
$decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secretkey, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$base64iv = base64_encode($iv);

$result = file_get_contents("http://SiteB.com/decrypt.php?urliv=$base64iv&something=$encrypted");

echo $result;
?>
```

Then the second:

```
<?php
//Site B - http://SiteB.com/decrypt.php
$iv_size = "32";
$base64iv = $_GET['urliv'];
$something = $_GET['something'];
$iv = base64_decode($base64iv);
$secretkey = hash ("md5", "0yFzFSlTEb7vla5Kv3BHvKcBzX4tJBId5UKAaDDr");

$decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secretkey, base64_decode($something), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);



echo "Decrypted Text " .  $decrypttext;
echo "<br><br>";
echo "IV Variable After Base64_Decode " . $iv;
?>
```

I can literally just sit there refreshing the screen for the Site A script, and it just works/doesn't work/almost works and I have no idea why.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that you get a response each time from siteb

Comment: Yes, it gets a response every single time otherwise there would be nothing for me to see on the screen (it is using file_get_contents("site B here with parameters")

Comment: and on SiteA `$decrypttext` is equal to `something` ? And `$iv` on siteA has the same value than `$iv` on siteB?

Comment: Did you get any answer to this?